# Inserting a new row while updating a row in the same table using MySQL triggers

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, insert, insert-update

I'm trying to insert a row into a table after updating a row in this same table. I was trying to do this using a trigger. But I found that it's not possible to do that in this method.

What i'm trying to achieve is, I have this 
tbl_eq_maintenance(eq_no,eq_name,last_rep_date,next_rep_date,status)

Values(EQ-30,treadmill,08-10-2018,18-10-2018,0).

I want to update this row's status into "1" and after that insert a new row into the same table as follows.
(EQ-30,treadmill,18-10-2018,28-10-2018,0). 
How can i do this with a trigger or if can't is there a workaround for this.

The trigger I wrote as below.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER add_maintenance 
    AFTER UPDATE on tbl_eq_maintenance
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE next_rep_date DATE;
    DECLARE new_m_cycle INT(5);

    SELECT m_cycle INTO new_m_cycle FROM tbl_equipments WHERE eq_no = NEW.eq_no;
    SET next_rep_date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL new_m_cycle DAY);
    INSERT INTO tbl_eq_maintenance (eq_no,eq_name,last_rep_date,next_rep_date)
    Values (NEW.eq_no,NEW.eq_name,CURDATE(),next_rep_date);

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger other than to set NEW. /OLD. values.

Comment: What can I do instead? @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

When you update the table, this trigger will execute and insert an new record in the table.

Refer to this [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php)